# WhatsApp group messages are not in order

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

For the past 3 days, my WhatsApp group messages are not getting downloaded (when I switch on WiFi) in order of time. Rather, it looks like they are grouped as per contacts. I looked into this site, and as suggested, tried the following:

1. Change your phone to use "Automatic Date and Time": didn't help
2. Reinstall WhatsApp: didn't help
3. Checked the WiFi connection: no issue with the WiFi, web is running perfectly in the same phone
4. Removed unnecessary apps which might delay things by totally resetting my phone to factory default, then reinstall WhatsApp: didn't help

What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known problem/bug and no solution has been found to this problem. So, your phone is working perfectly, no need to worry. When Whatsapp team gets a solution to this problem,  they will probably release an update.

Comment: Well I observed one interesting thing that, it is happening only in one group that I am connected to. In the other groups that I am connected, they messages are in perfect order

Comment: That's because it is a bug. Even the whatsapp team is not able to understand this strange behaviour, otherwise they would have fixed it.

Comment: I am also facing this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info...Will wait for the whatsapp team to get back